# iTerm2 keeps recreating symlink

Tags: config, symlink, iterm2

### Problem

I created a symlink awhile back from `~/Library/Application Support/iTerm2` to `~/.config/iterm2/AppSupport` (for convenience when I was moving all my configs into a managed repo in accordance with the [XDG structure](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html)). Having finished my work on iTerm preferences, I want to cleanup the repo and delete the symlink.
But even after deleting it, the symlink always reappears on restart of iTerm2.

### Attempts

1. Tried creating a new iterm config folder, but it always recreates the symlink in the original location `~/.config/iterm2/AppSupport`
2. Tried removing the Application Support folder, but it just gets recreated
3. Tried removing the SavedState sticky bit, but just gets recreated
4. Tried looking through the prefs in `com.googlecode.iterm2.plist` but didn't see anything relevant (maybe I overlooked?).

Is this due to iTerm2 running a long lasting server that remember some type of state including symlinks that are pointing to its Application Support folder?

### Temp Solution

The application works with my custom preferences location, so my current solution is just adding `iterm2/AppSupport` to my `.gitgnore`, but would like to know why this is happening.

```
$ tree -aL 2 ~/.config/iterm2                                                                                                                                                                                                               
.
├── .hushlogin
├── AppSupport -> /Users/mubuntu/Library/Application Support/iTerm2
│   ├── DynamicProfiles
│   ├── SavedState
│   │   ├── lock
│   │   ├── restorable-state.sqlite
│   │   ├── restorable-state.sqlite-shm
│   │   └── restorable-state.sqlite-wal
│   ├── Scripts
│   ├── iTermServer-3.4.23
│   ├── iterm2-daemon-1.socket
│   ├── iterm2-daemon-1.socket.lock
│   ├── parsers
│   │   ├── 46594f23855769cc8bbf0908a02b520fa9aabad0151b53d1a2a51fe351452aed
│   │   └── 47968eaa6beb856315113397c1b1c7848b7127dcd7bddb6df5380f941f8632d5
│   └── version.txt
├── com.googlecode.iterm2.plist
├── configure_iterm2.zsh
├── fonts
│   ├── FontPatcher.zip
│   ├── SauceCodeProNerdFont.zip
│   ├── SourceCodePro+Powerline+Awesome+Regular.ttf
│   └── SourceCodePro.zip
├── modern.itermkeymap
└── sourdiesel.itermcolors
```